# Print Screen button is not working

Tags: 13.04, gnome, shortcut-keys, print-screen

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and as a shell, Gnome 3.
After I have updated Ubuntu to 13.04, the Print Screen Button does nothing, though in the System Settings at the Keyboard Shortcuts, in the Screenshot section I have the following:

[image]

I have even tried to make my custom shortcut to gnome-screenshot, but it still doesn't work.
The only way I can take a screenshot is by pressing Alt+F2 and then typing "gnome-screenshot", or typing this in the terminal.
It is weird that in Unity the Print Screen button works.

Comment: No, it is not. I have seen that thread months ago and it did not helped.

Comment: Have you upgraded to 13.10? Does it work now? I would anyways recommend to upgrade as 13.04 is already in its 9th and last month of the official support period.

Comment: Maybe the other question relates to the behaviour of Gnome in 12.0

Comment: @Aditya Yes, I upgraded to 13.10 in October and it got stuck when booting at the Ubuntu logo screen. So... I've changed the GNU/Linux distro to Linux Mint.

Comment: @Robertfrost: In that case, do want to keep this question open? Since, you are not running Ubuntu anymore, we won't be able to know if any of the solutions (if provided) would solve the issue. I would presume that if you reinstall Ubuntu or run a live environment of Ubuntu, you won't face the same issue again.

Comment: Ok then. Feel free to close the question.